# Retrofit/OkHttp api calls not completing: "read: unexpected EOF!" printed

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Rx to batch requests to an api. There are currently 5 calls being made. I have a line in my code that prints out when the responses return. When executing the code, I often find only 4 lines printed, meaning not all 5 calls completed. Taking a look in logcat, i see the following message:

> read: unexpected EOF!

I came across this issue on github: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1228

I tried adding `@Streaming` on top of the @GET request that is being used, but this did not seem to fix the issue.

Where can I start debugging this, and what might be the issue?

Comment: I stumbled to same problem. Is your device is Xiaomi?

Comment: Yeah i am facing the same problem and my device is Xiaomi

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution here
https://sites.google.com/site/zhuoweisite/blog/fixingreadunexpectedeoferrorwhenusinglogcatonandroid80

execute this command on your terminal

```
adb logcat -G 1m
```

Answer (score 0):

In **manifest.xml** set

> android:largeHeap="true"

this is working for me